Image load error Webview Android (droid logo)
In some devices when I try to load a image url in a WebView I get the following (error) image:

Other devices load the image with no problems, how can I fix that?

What type of image are you talking about? Simple JPEG or PNG image or something more special like webp or hvec? What Android versions were running your test devices?

A simple PNG in Android 11

Is the problem specific to the file or the way how you load it (does it work with other png files)? Is the PNG file public -> URL? How do you load the image file?
